# Using custom virtual paths

Tags: asp.net

I'm making a test solution with just 2 or 3 pages organized in folders like this:

[image]

And when I run the app I get an url like this:

[image]

There is any way to maintain that Physical Path but having a different virtual path like

```
http://localhost:40300/Index.aspx
```

without the odd word "Views"?

Comment: Well... why did you put it in a Views folder anyway? Looks like an ASP.NET MVC file structure with WebForms pages...

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I just wanted to have the Views organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) for IIS. As an alternative, you can [create a custom HTTP module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) that will rewrite the virtual path appropriately:

```
public class MyRewriteHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
  // ...

  public void Init(HttpApplication app)
  {
    app.AuthenticateRequest += Application_AuthenticateRequest;
  }

  private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var app = sender as HttpApplication;
    var path = app.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

    if (!path.StartsWith("/Views/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      app.Context.RewritePath("/Views/" + path);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, for this solution I need access to the IIS right? But I only have access to publish into a ftp

Comment: Sorry, I was with a lot of work. I didn't made a strong testing but works fine. Marked as accepted answer. Best regards!